# JavaScript says that a programmed function which is called by another is not defined

Tags: javascript

In an Ionic-app i have a problem with one of my JavaScript functions which is called by another one.
I always get an error, that the function getSqlSelect is not defined.
But the functions are all defined in the services.js script.

Here's a short version of the code from services.js:

```
.factory('LocalDatabase', function () {
    var arrResult = "";

    return {
        select: function (table, filterAttributesArr, success) {
            var sql = getSqlSelect(table, filterAttributesArr);
            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'p16.sqlite', location: 0 });
        },
        getSqlSelect: function (tablename, filterAttributesArr) {
            return "";
        }

    };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't have a `getSqlSelect` variable in scope in that location. **If** `select` is called as `obj.select(...)` where `obj` is that object returned by the callback to factory, then within it you can use `this.getSqlSelect(...)` to refer to it. E.g.

```
var sql = this.getSqlSelect(table, filterAttributesArr);
//        ^^^^^
```

---

If `select` *isn't* called with the right `this`, that won't work. If you don't need to expose it, just define it within your callback:

```
.factory('LocalDatabase', function () {
    var arrResult = "";

    function getSqlSelect(tablename, filterAttributesArr) {
        return "";
    }

    return {
        select: function (table, filterAttributesArr, success) {
            var sql = getSqlSelect(table, filterAttributesArr);
            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'p16.sqlite', location: 0 });
        }
    };
})
```

---

If `select` isn't called with the right `this` and you **do** need to expose `getSqlSelect`, you can do that too:

```
.factory('LocalDatabase', function () {
    var arrResult = "";

    function getSqlSelect(tablename, filterAttributesArr) {
        return "";
    }

    return {
        select: function (table, filterAttributesArr, success) {
            var sql = getSqlSelect(table, filterAttributesArr);
            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'p16.sqlite', location: 0 });
        },
        getSqlSelect: getSqlSelect
    };
})
```

Comment: Thank You very much T.J.! That was the solution :)